# Why am I getting "ORA-01429: Index-Organized Table" when trying to modify column from VARCHAR2(200) to VARCHAR2(1000)?

Tags: oracle, alter-table, varchar2

It's currently a `VARCHAR2(200)` in the database, but it needs to be raised to `VARCHAR(1000)`, so I am attempting to run this script:

```
ALTER TABLE CONTRACTOR MODIFY
(
    NOTE VARCHAR2(1000)
);
```

Oracle gives me this:

> ORA-01429: Index-Organized Table: no data segment to store overflow row-pieces

This is a 10g database.  Any ideas what's up?  I could create a duplicate column, copy the data over, and then drop the old column, but I would like to know what this error is first before I do that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#i2128810), you need to specify an overflow segment for rows that might be to large to fit in a single block.

Consider (10.2.0.3 -- 8k blocks):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE contractor (
  2     ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  3     data_1 CHAR(1000),
  4     data_2 CHAR(1000),
  5     data_3 CHAR(1000),
  6     data_4 CHAR(1000),
  7     data_5 CHAR(1000),
  8     NOTE VARCHAR2(200)
  9  ) 
 10  ORGANIZATION INDEX;

ORA-01429: Index-Organized Table: no data segment to store overflow row-pieces
```

However, when you specify an overflow segment:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE contractor (
  2     ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  3     data_1 CHAR(1000),
  4     data_2 CHAR(1000),
  5     data_3 CHAR(1000),
  6     data_4 CHAR(1000),
  7     data_5 CHAR(1000),
  8     NOTE VARCHAR2(200)
  9  )
 10  ORGANIZATION INDEX 
 11  OVERFLOW TABLESPACE USER_DATA;

Table created
```

Comment: And you can't have any index entry span blocks - which is why the limitation still exists.  You can't index a VARCHAR2(4000) in a tablespace with a 2K block size.

Answer (score 1):

you can run sql:
alter table table_name add overflow;
then run your sql

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I came across this highly ranked page
when i googled 'ORA-01429'. I also faced the same exception when i was trying to **split OVERFLOW partition** in a Oracle 11G table.

```
*Incorrect*:
alter table sales SPLIT PARTITION OVERFLOW at (TO_DATE('01-FEB-2017 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) 
  INTO (PARTITION sales_m01_2017, PARTITION OVERFLOW);

*Fixed*:
alter table sales SPLIT PARTITION OVERFLOW at (TO_DATE('01-FEB-2017 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) 
  INTO (PARTITION sales_m01_2017, PARTITION "OVERFLOW");
```

I got the fix for my problem at following: 
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2244949?tstart=0

OVERFLOW has to be double quoted like "OVERFLOW". I though to share it here in the interest of other stackoverflow fans facing the same ORA exception while spliting OVERFLOW partition.